# Get next enumerator constant/property

Tags: python, python-3.x, enums, enumeration

Lets's say I have an enumerator, is it possible to get the property that follows? So if I had `today=Days.Sunday` would I be able to do something like `tomorrow=today.next()`?

example:

```
class Days(Enum):
     Sunday = 'S'
     Monday = 'M'
     ...
     Saturday = 'Sa'
```

I know I could use tuples (like below) to do something like `tomorrow=today[1]`, but I was hoping there was something built in or more elegant.

```
class Days(Enum):
     Sunday = ('S','Monday')
     Monday = ('M','Tuesday')
     ...
     Saturday = ('Sa','Sunday')
```

Comment: create some kind of iterator?

Comment: Thanks @PadraicCunningham, would that be more efficient than the tuple solution I have? I like yours more, I am just curious if it would save memory or run time :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Absolutely.

Just add the desired functionality to your `Days` class:

```
class Days(Enum):

    Sunday = 'S'
    Monday = 'M'
    Tuesday = 'T'
    Wednesday = 'W'
    Thursday = 'Th'
    Friday = 'F'
    Saturday = 'Sa'

    def next(self):
        cls = self.__class__
        members = list(cls)
        index = members.index(self) + 1
        if index >= len(members):
            index = 0
        return members[index]
```

and in use:

```
today = Days.Wednesday
print(today.next())
# Days.Thursday
```

---

While the above is probably easier to understand, it is possible to do the work once in `__init__` by adding a `next` attribute to each member (and `previous` while we're at it).

```
class Days(Enum):
    #
    Sunday = 'S'
    Monday = 'M'
    Tuesday = 'T'
    Wednesday = 'W'
    Thursday = 'Th'
    Friday = 'F'
    Saturday = 'Sa'
    #
    def __init__(self, value):
        if len(self.__class__):
            # make links
            all = list(self.__class__)
            first, previous = all[0], all[-1]
            previous.next = self
            self.previous = previous
            self.next = first
```

and in use:

```
>>> Days.Tuesday.next
<Days.Wednesday: 'W'>

>>> Days.Tuesday.previous
<Days.Monday: 'M'>

>>> Days.Saturday.next
<Days.Sunday: 'S'>

>>> Days.Saturday.previous
<Days.Friday: 'F'>
```

**NB** Using the this method of attributes means we no longer need the `()`s after `next`/`previous`.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a dictionary to lookup the next day like so:

```
In [10]: class Days(Enum):
    Sun = 'Su'
    Mon = 'M'
    Tue = 'Tu'
    Wed = 'W'
    Thu = 'Th'
    Fri = 'F'
    Sat = 'Sa'

In [11]: days = list(Days)

In [12]: nxt = dict((day, days[(i+1) % len(days)]) for i, day in enumerate(days))
```

Quick test:

```
In [13]: nxt[Days.Tue]
Out[13]: <Days.Wed: 'W'>

In [14]: nxt[Days.Sat]
Out[14]: <Days.Sun: 'Su'>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#ENUM CLASS

#colors
import enum

class Color(enum.Enum):
    turquoise = 1
    indigo = 2
    magenta = 3
    cyan = 4
    teal = 5
    azure = 6
    rose = 7
    amber = 8
    vermillon = 9
    plum = 10
    russet = 11
    slate = 12

    def __iter__(self):
        self.idx_current = self.value
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        if (self.idx_current > 12):
            return None

        self.idx_current = self.idx_current + 1
        return Color (self.idx_current - 1)

#CLIENT CODE
    #iterate colors starting from cyan
    it = iter (Color.cyan)
    while True:
        #print (v.get_id())
        c = next (it)
        if c is None:
            break
        print(c)

#OUTPUT
Color.cyan
Color.teal
Color.azure
Color.rose
Color.amber
Color.vermillon
Color.plum
Color.russet
Color.slate
```

Comment: It would make more sense to raise [`StopIteration`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#StopIteration) rather than return `None` from `__next__()`.

Answer (score 0):

For me that seems like the most elegant solution without additional functions

```
day = Days.Sunday

day = Days((day.value + 1) % len(Days) + 1) # next day cycled
```