# How can I implement an increment function for enum objects?

Tags: python, enums

I'm working with a Dyson fan and am trying to write a function that increases the speed of the fan. The enum object FanSpeed has the following members. When I execute [print(i) for i in FanSpeed] I get:

```
FanSpeed.FAN_SPEED_1
FanSpeed.FAN_SPEED_2
FanSpeed.FAN_SPEED_3
FanSpeed.FAN_SPEED_4
FanSpeed.FAN_SPEED_5
FanSpeed.FAN_SPEED_6
FanSpeed.FAN_SPEED_7
FanSpeed.FAN_SPEED_8
FanSpeed.FAN_SPEED_9
FanSpeed.FAN_SPEED_10
```

So the first enum object (above) has the name FAN_SPEED_1 (`FanSpeed.FAN_SPEED_1.name`) and has a value of "0001" (`FanSpeed.FAN_SPEED_1.value`), and so on.

The function to set speed (to 5 in this example is):

```
fan.set_configuration(fan_mode=FanMode.FAN, fan_speed=FanSpeed.FAN_SPEED_5)
```

I can't figure out how to write a function that gets the current speed and then sets it to one level higher. I've tried:

1/ Treating the enum object as a a string and replacing the last character with a number (character type) that's higher. This approach doesn't work for enum objects though.

2/ Looking for some kind of increment or next function but those don't seem to exist for enum objects.

Comment: how do you access the current speed from the fan config ? you could search the index of this result in your list, then increase/decrease of 1 or more

Comment: Another duplicate, but with a different technique:  [`Get next enumerator constant/property`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35905666/208880)

Comment: Personally, I found this question and answer more concise and easier to wrap my head around than the one cited as a duplicate.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

So let's use the example from Python documentation:

```
from enum import Enum
class Color(Enum):
    RED = 1
    GREEN = 2
    BLUE = 3

current_color = Color.RED
new_color = Color(current_color.value + 1)
>>> new_color == Color.GREEN
True
```

Thanks, I've yet to play with the Enum type, so this was a good learning experience.

If you want to do this for non-int values you could do the following:

```py
class Color(Enum):
    red = "0001"
    blue = "0002"


def get_next_color(current_color):
    current_color_idx = list(Color).index(current_color)
    next_color_idx = (current_color_idx + 1) % len(Color)
    next_color = list(Color)[next_color_idx]
    return next_color
```

Comment: Thanks, got it to work. Small note - the values are strings like "0001" so I had to take the last character, convert to int, increment by 1, then add the "000" back. Besides that, answer is perfect..

Comment: Nice answer, have an up-vote.  :)

Comment: Thanks. I like the original's answer because it works in all cases, especially this one. @marlonmisra I almost provided an answer to that, but I wasn't sure if that was the question. Even though I like my solution, I'd go with the other answer. I'm surprised that's not a built-in method.

Comment: One issue with this is that it is sensitive to overflow (incrementing BLUE gives a value error). For my needs I wanted to wrap around and so I used `new_color = Color((current_color.value + 1) % len(Color))`. Alternatively you could choose to only increment `if current_color != Color.BLUE`.

Comment: Is there a good way to do this when the enum values aren't integers?

Comment: @CtrlAltF2 I've added a solution to my answer that would do such a thing