# Is there a simple method for circularly iterating over an enum?

Tags: python-3.x, loops, enums

I have an enum class that stores 4 seasons and would like to be able to move to the next season. When I get to the end (FALL), I want it to go back to the first one (WINTER). Is there a simple way of doing this or am I better off just using a list or some other structure. Some answers I've found online seem like overkill so I'm curious if using an enum is even worth it.

```
from enum import Enum, auto

class Season(Enum):
    WINTER = auto()
    SPRING = auto()
    SUMMER = auto()
    FALL   = auto()
```

```
>>> season = Season.SUMMER
>>> season.next()
<Season.FALL: 4>
>>> season.next()
<Season.WINTER: 1>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since `Enum` already supports the iteration protocol, that is *very* easy, using [`itertools.cycle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle):

```
>>> from itertools import cycle
>>> seasons = cycle(Season)
>>> next(seasons)
<Season.WINTER: 1>
>>> next(seasons)
<Season.SPRING: 2>
>>> next(seasons)
<Season.SUMMER: 3>
>>> next(seasons)
<Season.FALL: 4>
>>> next(seasons)
<Season.WINTER: 1>
```

Comment: If this is not sufficient, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26577621/get-next-enumerator-constant-property